# How to terminate a workflow based on the status of an item - SP 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a list that has more than a few hundred items. Within this list is a Status column and a workflow published to it.

I want to terminate/cancel a workflow for items that have the Status of "**Closed**" or "**Not Implemented**".

If this is possible, how can this be done?

In addition to cancelling WFs based on a status of an item, is it also possible to stop a WF based on the date it was created?

**For example:**

If Status = Closed or Not Implemented AND Created before 08/01/2016 then STOP the WF.

If not possible to stop a WF based on Created no worries but would still want to know if it's possible to stop WFs based on Status of any given item. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The Workflow is made using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Status it can be iterating to the said workflowcollection and looping for the field based on which you can cancel/stop the workflow.

Check the below link hope this helps!
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5fc79f8-ca3a-421a-ab8a-78fcb3365b46/terminating-a-sharepoint-workflow-programatically?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Let me know if it works out!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but the WF was made using Designer 2013 and not VS. Also doesn't specify how to terminate a WF made in Designer based on a given condition. I was hoping maybe if there was a PS article that details how to do so.